# How to make join between 2 tables using 2 values?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

In Mariadb database I want to make a query to join two tables: `joke` and `jokevote` to get all jokes which are upvoted by a certain user.

Here are the tables:

**joke**

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(6) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | None              |                |
| content     | mediumtext       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0                 |                |
| username    | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | Unknown           |                |
...
```

**jokevote:**

```
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| joke_id | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vote    | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The content of `jokevote` is:
[image]

Some values in `joke` table (related to user 6):
[image]

One of the query that I tried is:

```
    SELECT * FROM joke LEFT JOIN jokevote 
     ON joke.user_id=6  AND joke.id=jokevote.joke_id 
     AND jokevote.vote=1;
```

The query should return only 2 jokes, but it returns all of the jokes. 
I've also tried other queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM joke LEFT JOIN jokevote 
ON joke.user_id=6  AND joke.id=jokevote.joke_id AND 
jokevote.vote=1 AND joke.user_id=jokevote.user_id AND ;
```

(again, returns all of the jokes)

So I'm left clueless and wondering what's the correct query in this case?

Comment: show also a data sample  and the expcted  result

Comment: LEFT join returns all records from the LEFT side of the query. So it will always return all joke records in your case. Maybe you are looking for INNER JOIN?

Comment: Use `join` instead of `left join`

Comment: @scaisEdge Data samples added.

Comment: now are unseful .. you have already a right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to do a `INNER JOIN` instead saying

```
SELECT * FROM joke INNER JOIN jokevote 
 ON joke.id=jokevote.joke_id 
 WHERE jokevote.vote=1
 AND joke.user_id=6;
```

Comment: This returns 0 rows, while it should return 2 jokes.

Comment: @Karlom, post sample data for `joke` table as well

Comment: Just added sample data of both tables. Please have a look.

Comment: @Karlom, you aren't getting data cause there is no record in joke table with id 10 and 17 which matches the `where` conditions

Comment: Shame on me! yes, I just figured out.